# C compiler error: .\list.h:17:1: error: unknown type name 'Node'

Tags: c

I got this error while I compile the sourcefile, it said I used a unknown type, but I have already declared a struct Node before. This is the part of source code:

```
typedef int Datatype;

struct Node  // <--- declaration is here
{
    Datatype Data;
    struct Node *Next;
};

typedef struct Node *List;

struct Node* makeEmpty()       // <-- .\list.h:17:1: error: unknown type name 'Node'
{
    struct Node* list = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*)); // Allocate memory to dummy node
    list = NULL;
    return list; 
}
```

Comment: compiles fine for me, so this isnt what you got, only what you think you have - or - they arent in the same file . https://ideone.com/LWTSSL

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. The code you show here compiles fine.

Comment: The error message looks as if you used type `Node` without `struct` keyword somewhere. But there is no issue in the code you show.